# Ie doesnt like range

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, wysiwyg

I have a WYSIWYG editor working in all browsers except IE (all versions). I have a problem with the function below:

```
function tag(tag) {
    var range = window.frames['textEditor'].getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var newNode = document.createElement(tag);
    range.surroundContents(newNode);
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE doesn't support range, because it's a big baby. However, it will do what you want, but with separate logic. Check out the [Quirksmode Range Page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html) for info on how to whip IE into shape.

Comment: i have the following that works outside the iframe in ie, if i am trying to detect that the selected text is in the iframe in ie it does not work  var userSelection;
if (window.getSelection) {
 alert("none IE");
 userSelection = window.getSelection();
}
else if (document.selection) { // should come last; Opera!
alert("IE");
 userSelection = document.selection.createRange();
}

Answer (score 2):

IE < 9 doesn't have support for standard DOM Range and Selection. For an implementation of these APIs that works in these and all major browsers, you could use my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library.

As an aside, using the `surroundContents()` method of a range will only work when the range starts and ends in the same node or children of the same node. For example, it will not work for a range such as the following (with range boundaries denoted by square brackets):

```
One |two <b>three| four</b>
```

To style ranges like this you'll need a more subtle approach.

Answer (score 0):

i Have it working in  all browsers now if anyone needs the script i will post it bellow

```
   function changeHeading(heading) {

  if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 7 || $.browser.version == 8)
  {
    theSelection = window.frames['textEditor'].document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
    window.frames['textEditor'].document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML("<"+heading+">"+theSelection+"</"+heading+">")
    $("#textEditor").contents().find(heading).unwrap();
  }

  else {
    var needle =window.frames['textEditor'].getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var haystack = $('#textEditor').contents().find("body").text();
    var newText = haystack.replace(needle,"<"+heading+">"+needle+"</"+heading+">");
    $('#textEditor').contents().find("body").html(newText);
    $("#textEditor").contents().find(heading).unwrap();
}
}
```

Thanks for the help